# How to send Webhook Requests to Microsoft Teams?

Tags: java, discord, microsoft-teams

I made a Discord Bot in Java for my School Class, and because of Corona, we have an online class at the moment.

Now, because all of the subjects have a different Team, I want to integrate into the bot, that it sends a message to Discord when someone creates a new Meeting to make it easier because my school mates are more frequent online on Discord than on Teams.

I thought about webhooks, but unfortunately, my google research only put out tutorials on how to send Webhook Requests *to* Microsoft Teams, but not *from* Microsoft Teams.

Is there any way to do that? Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't know for certain, but I don't think this is possible. I would imagine that Microsoft doesn't release that kind of data in the interest of security.

Comment: Also if I would log me in or something with an API token? Like if I log myself in to verify I'm allowed to see that information?

Comment: It looks like there is an API for it, but unfortunately not even school or work accounts get access to this information. I'll leave you the link if you want to read more into it 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onlinemeeting?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: This may help, in regards to getting permission, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-outgoing-webhook). You can let microsoft teams send webhooks to your bot and the bot sends a message to discord, then. It might be possible that discord supports microsoft teams webhooks but I don't think so.